# Using name of strings in different functions

Tags: python, string, function

I need to use `movies_list` from the first function in the second. How do I do that?

```
def movie():
    movies_list = [movie.strip() for movie in movies_list]
    movie_explorer()

def rand():
    rand_item = print(random.choice(movies_list))
```

Comment: Why not make it one function? `movie` takes no variables.

Comment: Poor example, as not even `movie` will work. Try calling it and you'll see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### ***The Good***

Use `return` and arguments

```
def movie():
    movies_list = [movie.strip() for movie in movies_list]
    movie_explorer()
    return movies_list

def rand(movies_list):
    rand_item = print(random.choice(movies_list))
```

And when calling `rand` remember to call the function as

```
rand(movie())
```

### ***The Bad***

Add a line

```
global movies_list
```

as the first line in both functions

### ***And the Ugly***

You can make use of the `globals` object available. (Adding it here to complete the rhyme)

```
def movie():
    global movie_returns
    movie_returns = [movie.strip() for movie in movies_list]
    movie_explorer()
    # No return

def rand():  # No argument
    movies_list = next((globals()[v] for v in globals() if v=='movies_return'))
    rand_item = random.choice(movies_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the second function nested on the first one, here you have an example:

```
def hello():
    a = "hello"
    def world():
        return "%s world" % a
    return world()
print hello()
```

Answer (score -1):

put the two functions in a class, and make *movies_list* a class variable.

Comment: Why a class? That would be much too complicated.

Comment: what's complicated about classes?